# Stop Spring MVC annotations processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I need to stop processing of Spring MVC annotations on interface, but bean for this interface should be created.
e.g. I have shared Api interface with MVC REST annotations, Controller implements this Api. In other project I create REST client based on interface (by processing annotations). But when I create client, Spring sees interface as return type and process annotations inside it. So, I need to stop annotations processing when I create REST client, but for controller annotations should work (now they work OK).

```
@RequestMapping("/resource1")
public interface Api {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    Resource1 getResource1();
}

@RestController
public class Controller implements Api {
    @Override
    public Resource1 getResource1() {
         return null;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public Api api() {
         return RestClientFactory.createRestClientBasedOnAnnotations(Api.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating new annotation which is used to mark API interface and overriding `boolean isHandler(Class<?> beanType)` method of `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. This method originally checks whether class (or any interface that class implements) is annotated with `Controller` or `RequestMapping` annotations. I added extra check that looks up for my `BackEndApiInterface` annotation and if it is found then return `false`. Here is the code:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BackEndApiInterface {
}

@BackEndApiInterface 
@RequestMapping("/resource1")
public interface Api {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    Resource1 getResource1();
}

@RestController
public class Controller implements Api {
    @Override
    public Resource1 getResource1() {
        return null;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public Api api() {
         return RestClientFactory.createRestClientBasedOnAnnotations(Api.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public static RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
            @Override
            protected boolean isHandler(Class<?> beanType) {
                if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanType, BackEndApiInterface.class) != null) {
                    return false;
                }
                return super.isHandler(beanType);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could move the annotations to the implementation and just keep the interface as pure java.

Comment: Interface is shared and is used to create/generate REST client based on annotations. Basically it synchronizes REST URLs, method, parameter through server and client apps.